# Hierarchical Clustering and the probability that belonging a cluster - Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

I have bunch of data.I am clustering this data with hierarchical clustering algorithm. How can i find the probability that an instance belongs to a cluster. When I found probability, I will make some calculations.Then, I will add this instance my train set according to result.

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical clustering does not compute a probability. It is not a probabilistic model - it does not provide probabilities.

So you will have to come up with your own modeling approach, and I don't think it will be easy to retrofit a probability model onto this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new column with the cluster assignments to your data set, click "Filter" / "Unsupervised" / "attribute" / "AddCluster" (Then parameterize the clustering algorithm) / "Apply Filter". This will add the Cluster ID, that Weka thinks is appropriate for this parameterization, as a new column in your dataset.

But this won't give you any "probabilities of cluster assignments" because that's -as user Anony-Mousse remarked- not how hierarchical clustering works.